# Cordova audio visualizer? (with Media instead of AnalyserNode)

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova, audio

I made a visualizer using the Web Audio API's AnalyserNode on my desktop website, but now that I'm in PhoneGap/Cordova, I don't know how to replicate that with the Native APIs available to me. I'm using the Media class instead of HTML5's conventional Audio-related classes, so I don't think I can just hook them up with `.connect()`. Is there any way I can do this on at least Android KitKat and/or iOS 7?

Comment: Sorry for the last message but did you ever find some sort of solution or alternative framework for this? I'm struggling with the exact same problem at the moment!